# appcrash when detouring LoadLibraryA

Tags: c++, winapi, detours

I detoured LoadLibraryA, in order to block the function from being called into my app. It is meant to block'dll injection'. Please refer to the well-known CDetour library if you've never seen these.

It hooks the load library function and even returns sucessfully, also blocking unknown dll's from being loaded into the memory. Any tips?

```
bool ( __stdcall* LoadLibraryA ) ( LPCSTR );

bool LoadLibraryADetoured( LPCSTR szMsg )
{
    if( strcmp( szMsg, "MyAllowedDll.dll" ) )
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}

INT APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID Reserved )
{
    switch( dwReason )
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            {
                DWORD dwRetAddress = (DWORD)GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandleA( "kernel32.dll" ), "LoadLibraryA" );
                ZChatInput = ( bool ( __stdcall* ) ( ) )LoadLibraryA( ( PBYTE )dwRetAddress, ( PBYTE )LoadLibraryADetoured );
                DisableThreadLibraryCalls( hModule );
                break;
            }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            DetourRemove( ( PBYTE )dwRetAddress, ( PBYTE )LoadLibraryADetoured );
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: `LoadLibraryA` doesn't take 2 arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN, there are severe limitations of what you can safely do in `DllMain()`. `LoadLibrary()` is not safe there for sure.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx:

> Because Kernel32.dll is guaranteed to be loaded in the process address space when the entry-point function is called, calling functions in Kernel32.dll does not result in the DLL being used before its initialization code has been executed. Therefore, the entry-point function can call functions in Kernel32.dll **that do not load other DLLs**. For example, DllMain can create synchronization objects such as critical sections and mutexes, and use TLS. Unfortunately, there is not a comprehensive list of safe functions in Kernel32.dll.

(Bold emphasis is mine)

Comment: Thanks! it worked!, I used __beginthreadex instead on the process attach to detours.

Comment: Yes it asked me to wait 5 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Your detour needs to use the same calling convention as the function being detoured.  `LoadLibraryA()` uses `__stdcall` but your detour uses the compiler default, which is usually `__cdecl` instead.